# Bootnode from geth not working with parity

Tags: parity

**I am working with Parity private network. I can manually add peers for each node and it works. But the problem is Bootnode executable from geth not working with Parity.**

`bootnode.exe -nodekey=key.txt -verbosity 9 -addr 127.0.0.1:30308`

In parity config.tomal

> *bootnodes = ["enode://6d5fe9514018fd79cb4ba13ce1182ebc2e470fc19efd4a06d718c210a82559c88423a4ea841833bb00d1da23bc2b26425c415863b5bd776f8b3eb5dbc81d5bed@127.0.0.1:30308*"]

Hit is coming to bootnode but It can't recognize parity nodes.

Output:

```
TRACE[06-06|20:22:51] << FINDNODE/v4                           addr=127.0.0.1:30307 err="unknown node"
TRACE[06-06|20:22:54] << FINDNODE/v4                           addr=127.0.0.1:30305 err="unknown node"
TRACE[06-06|20:23:00] << FINDNODE/v4                           addr=127.0.0.1:30306 err="unknown node"
```

I have tried with -v5 also, no success.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Parity v1.11.3 seems to be solved this problem.
https://github.com/paritytech/parity/releases/tag/v1.11.3